# Error using dplyr::count() within purrr::map()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

In this example I want to apply the count() function to every character variable in a dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

nycflights13::flights %>% 
    select_if(is.character) %>% 
    map(., count)
```

But I receive the error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("groups") : no applicable method for 
'groups' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the error message or update my code. Similar code works for numeric variables, but factor variables produce a similar error message to character variables

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    map(., mean, na.rm = TRUE)

nycflights13::flights %>% 
    select_if(is.character) %>% 
    mutate_all(as.factor) %>% 
    map(., count)
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect the output to be? `count()` isn't meant to be used on character vectors -- you get the same error with `count(letters[1:10])`.

Comment: `count` is designed to work on a data frame, not a vector.

Comment: @MrFlick I was hoping to view the counts of unique values for each character variable in my dataset.

Comment: You either want `map(., table)` or `%>% count(.)` but they perform different things

Comment: But what type of data structure were you expecting? A list of data.frames with two columns (value, count)?

Comment: @MrFlick I was expecting a list of data.frames, but using the table() function as suggested by CPak is producing a named vector that can be converted to data.frames

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a list of tibbles with value counts, you can use

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  select_if(is.character) %>% 
  map(~count(data.frame(x=.x), x))
```

Comment: There's also `map_df` to output in data.frame format `map_df(~ count(data.frame(x = .), x), .id = "var")`. It's handy to use .id to distinguish between variables.

Comment: hey! @MrFlick, thank you for this answer. But can you help me explain how this works? For reading it, it appears you are first creating a data frame by extract each column of the source data frame but putting it in a single column. Then passing this single column dataframe into count. However why doesn't `map(~count(.))`  work by itself? Super curious

Comment: @alejandro_hagan The `count()` function is a dplyr function that expects a data.frame/tibble as the first parameter. When you use `map()` with a data.frame/tibble, you are mapping over the column values which are not tibbles. So if you want to use count, you need to turn those vectors into data.frames/tibbles.

Comment: thank you so much @MrFlick! I understand it much better now. I literally could not figure it out. I appreciate your response!