# How to use quasiquotation / tidy evaluation when doing `map` with column names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tidy

Could you help me understand how Quasiquotation works?
I'm using map and count function but it doesn't seem to work properly.

First try:

```
map(names(starwars),~starwars %>% count(.x))
Error: Column `.x` is unknown
```

Second try:

```
map(names(starwars),~starwars %>% count(!!.x))
#not useful [[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"name"`     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 name        87

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"height"`     n
  <chr>      <int>
1 height        87
```

Third try:

```
map(names(starwars),~starwars %>% count(!!!.x))
# the same
```

Another example (working on functions):

If I want to make a function that takes a list and the
changes each element of the list with regard to the previous element
on that list:

```
my_list <- list("a" =1 , "b" = 2, "c" = 3)

# this obviously is not working (list + number)
> my_list+1
Error in my_list + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# this is a bit strange
my_list %>% map(~+1)
#this works fine
my_list %>% map(+1)
# as this
my_list %>% map(~.x+1)

# moving on to add the previous element to the next element
imap(my_list, my_list[[.y +1]] := .x %>% +1)
Error in `:=`(my_list[[.y + 1]], .x %>% +1) : could not find function ":="

# wrong eval 1?
imap(my_list, my_list[[.y +1]] <- .x %>% +1)
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object '.x' not found

# wrong eval 2?
imap(my_list, my_list[[.y +1]] <- !!.x %>% +1)
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object '.x' not found

# wrong symbol 1?
imap(my_list, my_list[[.y +1]] = .x %>% +1)
Error: unexpected '=' in "imap(my_list, my_list[[.y +1]] ="
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49989886/12400385. It suggests you use `df %>% map(~count(data.frame(x=.x), x))`

Comment: It does not answer your question about quasinotation, but it provides a work around in your example so you don't need the bang bang. `starwars %>% select_if(negate(is.list)) %>% map(~count(data.frame(x=.x), x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question can be decomposed into a section on quasi-quotation and anoth on `map` functions.

First, `~ starwars %>% count(.x))` is shorthand for and a slightly more complicated version of `function(.x){starwars %>% count(.x)}`.  So I'm going to work with the functions directly.

Second, `names(starwars)` gives you a character vector.

So to avoid the confusion that `map` brings let's start with functions and pass them the character "eye_color".

## Attempt 1: `dplyr` functions treat symbols as if they are columns in the tbl

`dplyr` functions are nice when doing interactive data analysis, because they allow us to refer to columns with symbols. I recommend reading:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html  for more info.

```
func <- function(.x) { starwars %>% count(.x) }
func("eye_color")
Error: Column `.x` is unknown
```

In your first attempt, this leads to a problem, because `.x` is symbol, so R thinks `.x` is column in `starwars`.

## Attempt 2/3: `count()` / `group_by()` expect symbols not character input.

`!!` takes `.x` and replaces it with "eye_color". But "eye_color" is not symbol/name but rather a character.

```
func_2 <- function(.x) { starwars %>% count(!!.x) }
func_2("eye_color")

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"eye_color"`     n
  <chr>         <int>
1 eye_color        87
```

This weird output is the result of grouping by a character. For whatever reason, `dplyr` groups the whole dataframe  as "eye_color" and then tells you there are 87 rows. `starwars %>% count("hooray")` gives similar output.

## Interlude: what we want is a symbol

A somewhat intuitive way to code `dplyr` functions is to pass symbols/names and use `{{.x}}` to evaluate the promise. (Less intuitively you can do `!!enquo(.x)`.)

```
func_3 <- function(.x) {  starwars %>% count({{.x}}) }
func_3(eye_color)

# A tibble: 15 x 2
   eye_color         n
   <chr>         <int>
 1 black            10
 2 blue             19
 3 ...
```

This works!

## A solution is to convert the characters to symbols

```
func_4 <- function(.x) { .x = as.symbol(.x)
                         starwars %>% count({{.x}}) }
func_4("eye_color")

# A tibble: 15 x 2
   eye_color         n
   <chr>         <int>
 1 black            10
 2 blue             19
 3 ...
```

This also works!

## Bringing back `map`

Before I continue, I think nniloc's solution is better for your problem.

But you could use map as follows

```
starwars %>% 
  select_if(negate(is.list)) %>% 
  names() %>% 
  map(function(.x) {x = as.symbol(.x)
      starwars %>% count( {{ x }} )
      })
```

or

```
starwars %>% 
  select_if(negate(is.list)) %>% 
  names() %>% 
  map(as.symbol) %>%
  map(function(.x) { 
      starwars %>% count( {{  .x }} )
      })
```

When you use the `~` notation, `.x` is now a "pronoun" that refers to the symbols directly, so we can use `!!` to access the symbols directly. (I don't fully understand this).

```
starwars %>% 
  select_if(negate(is.list)) %>% 
  names() %>% 
  map(as.symbol) %>%
  map(~ starwars %>% count( !! .x  ))
```

Regarding `imap()`, it looks like you want to code in python (or some other language with iteration). `imap()` is short hand for `map2(.x, names(.x), ...)` so is distinct from `enumerate()` in python. There are R functions like `seq_along` which give you position in an object, but I haven't used those with map.

Comment: This is such a great answer. Thank you!